# Does SVN allow update selected directories in bath?

Tags: svn, automation

I have project with many branches and tags and with many directories. Is it possible write some scripts - so first script update only trunk, another only branch 1 etc, because now I waste many time to clock to update on more than 50 directories to check if there are new updates? So some kind of automation is need.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using command-line svn options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you shouldtn have them all checked out.... You should only check out the branch youre working (in this sense trunk is also a branch). Tags should NEVER change... typically you use a Tag as a snapshot of particular revision like a release so there would be no reason to update it.

That said if you have th eentire repo checkout for some reason you can just update the branch you want. Assuming you have the entire repo checked out to `/myrepo`:

```
cd /myrepo
svn up trunk
```

Comment: `for r in path/to/trunk also/to/branch1 moreover/branch2/as/well; do ( cd "$r"; svn up ); done`